ForceGraph3D node module dependency issue. . /webgpu
I recently ran an npm update for my nextjs/react app.  I now get this compiling error but connot figure out why.
./node_modules/three-render-objects/dist/three-render-objects.mjs:2:1
Package path ./webgpu is not exported from package /node_modules/three.
My package.json contains this:
"react-force-graph-3d": "^1.24.5",

Any help would be very much appreciated as I've spent hours on this issue.
